# Spikes every 5 minutes on AWS ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Take a look at this ec2 monitoring image. We have spikes every 5 minutes in our amazon ec2 large instance (ubuntu). How should we find the cause of these spikes?
Thanks!

[image: Spikes]

Comment: It can be because of many things. Try doing `ps -ef` every 10 seconds and also `top` and then compare the results.

Comment: Could you maybe give an idea of what you're running on the machine?

Comment: only `ps` can, as @fedorqui suggested

Comment: It's running nginx and php(used as a service for apps) and most calls are causing mysql queries (mysql is hosted on another server)

Comment: And do you have access to the Server Monitor of the data base? Maybe some complicated queries are being executed and require a lot of temp memory.

Comment: Yes i have access to the server monitor of the database. Nothing seems special there

Comment: OK. Then I would recommend to do something like `while true; do ps -ef >> /tmp/testing; sleep 1; done` for around 10 min. You will see aaaall the processes running for that time.

Comment: Thanks people! It helped. We have found the cause to be php fuser (clearing session files from disk). We have changed the sessions to use memcache instead and our problem is gone